WPF .net core 6 Image control does not work in .net core 6
I created a new WPF C# desktop application in VS 2022 using .net core 6. For some reason the image shows in the designer but when the application is running it does not show. If I create a WPF C# desktop application in VS 2022 using .net framework 4.8 the Image does work.
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source=".\Logo.jpg" Width="300" Height="300" />
        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red"/>        
    </StackPanel>
</Window>


The difference is the default Build Action of image files. Set it to Resource. And of course make sure to add the file to the project.

The issue is with .net core 6. It works in .net core 7 and 8. The build action does not fix this issue. And this question is NOT a duplicate!!!

So what is the Build Action you are intending to use? Is the image file supposed to be an assembly resource or a local file loaded from a relative path? Please add all relevant details that are necessary to understand your problem, ideally post a minimal reproducible example.

I did post a minimal reproducible example, and I posted the solution in my comment. Basically it is a bug in .net core 6, but I guess Stack Overflow does not deal with bugs. And again, it is NOT a duplicate. The image should show in debug no matter what the build action is.
